# How to filter by range of specific hours in Django Orm?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a queryset below, that allows me to get objects that where created at last 14 days:

```
qs_1 = Model.objects.filter(datetime_created__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=14))
```

What I want is to create a new queryset that will allow me to get objects for last 14 days and filter them by range from 11 pm to 9am. How can I do that ?

Comment: `datetime_created__hour__in=(start,end)`

Comment: that is not seems to work when start hour is bigger than end hour

Comment: @BurhanKhalid You probably meant `...__between`, not exactly `start` or exactly `end`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read examples about [**hour**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#hour) lookup.

> ... Takes an integer between 0 and 23.

I think that the most readable solution is:

```
from django.db.models import Q
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(datetime_created__hour__lt=9) |
                       Q(datetime_created__hour__gte=23))
```

An `lt` lookup is because you probably definitely don't want 09:00:01am or 09:59:59am and don't need 09:00:00am. The [time](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#time) lookup can be used in more complicated cases if minutes are important. A "filter" by `.exclude(...__hour__between=(8, 22))` is not a clear solution that could select also null timestamps and could have non trivial consequences like left joins etc. It requires to think longer than to read twice `datetime_created__hour...`.